# How to prove that complex matrices are similar?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove that, for every a in R, the complex matrices 
[image]

[image]

are similar?   *1*As I understand it sin represents the imaginary number while cos the real. *2*To show similarity there is a need for invertible matrix, but how does it work with complex matrix? Thanks in advance

Comment: how can we find matrix these two matrix are similar without using eigenvlaues just using concept of linear transformation

Answer (score 2):

Recall that two matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar iff there exists an invertible matrix $P$ that $A=P^{-1}BP$. Such definition also works for complex matrices.

Let's find the $P$ now. Denote $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}e^{i\alpha}&0\\0&e^{-i\alpha}\end{array}\right)$ and $B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos\alpha&-\sin\alpha\\\sin\alpha&\cos\alpha\end{array}\right)$. The eigenvalues of $B$ are obviously $e^{i\alpha}$ and $e^{-i\alpha}$.

Solve the equation $$Bx=\lambda_i x$$ where $\lambda_1=e^{i\alpha}$ and $\lambda_2=e^{-i\alpha}$. We can get the eigenvectors $x_1=\left(1,-i\right)^T$ and $x_2=\left(1,i\right)^T$.  Verify that $$P=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\-i&i\end{array}\right)$$ satisfy the similarity formula and we complete the proof.

Comment: How am I suppose make an inverse of P? Does it work like for real matrix?

Comment: You're right. Just do that like the way you do for real matrices.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For $x\in\Bbb R$ we have $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\,\sin x$ and $e^{-ix}=\cos x-i\sin x$.

The formula for inverse of $2\times 2$ matrix is the same.

Comment: Does not it suppose to involve 2x2 matrix such as [1 i][i1]

Answer (score 0):

Put

$$A:=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha&\!\!-\sin\alpha\\\sin\alpha&\;\;\cos\alpha\end{pmatrix}\;\;,\;\;B:=\begin{pmatrix}e^{i\alpha}&0\\0&e^{-i\alpha}\end{pmatrix}$$

Then the respective characteristic polynomials are:

$$p_A(x)=(x-\cos\alpha)^2+\sin^2\alpha=x^2-2x\cos\alpha+1$$

$$p_B(x)=(x-e^{i\alpha})(x-e^{-i\alpha})=x^2-2x\cos\alpha+1$$

and since in both cases clearly the minimal polynomial of both matrices is the same, then the matrices are similar.

**Caution!** : Having the same characteristic and minimal polynomials is sufficient and enough for similarity *as long as the order of the matrices is less than $\,4\,$* ; in this last case we already have counterexamples.

Answer (score 0):

$\LaTeX$ tip: try "\sin" and "\cos".  Your first matrix is not a complex matrix. This trick may help: two 2-by-2 matrices are similar if they have the same eigenvalues and the eigenvalues are distinct.  For your second matrix, the eigenvalues are just the diagonal elements.  Verify the first matrix has the same eigenvalues.  If $\alpha$ is not an integer multiple of $\pi$, the eigenvalues are distinct.  If $\alpha$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$, the eigenvalues are not distinct but then your matrices are equal multiples of $I$